# Detect circle in Opencv

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

When I try to detect circle from Coins Image:

In the first program, I use **Matlab** and everything works fine.

Now I try do detect The same circles from the coin's image but used **OpenCV** and I get a bad result.

I think that I do something wrong but I don't know what?

```matlab
% This Example for Hough Transform Circles Matlab
% First step read image and make pre-processing
img = imread('coins2.png'); % Coins Image is Gray
figure, imshow(img), title('Orignal Coins Image');
edges = edge(img, 'Canny', [0.01, 0.5]);
figure, imshow(edges), title('Edge Image');
% Second Step Find all circles with radius [Rmin,Rmax]
Rmin = 10;   
Rmax = 40;
[center, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(edges, [Rmin, Rmax]);
% Retain the N strongest circles according to the metric values
N = 24; % Hyperparam I can choose or I can display all circles that I get from the voting
centerStrong = center(1:N,:);
radiusStrong = radii(1:N);
metricStrong = metric(1:N);
% Draw the N strongest circle perimeters over the original image.
figure, imshow(img), hold on, viscircles(centerStrong, radiusStrong,'EdgeColor','b'), 
title('Circle Segment'), hold off;
```

[image]

```py
# Python exam:
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('coins2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Convert the image to gray scale
edges = cv2.Canny(image=gray, threshold1=200, threshold2=100, apertureSize=3)
cv2.imshow('Orignal Image', img), cv2.imshow('Edge Image', edges)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image=edges, method=cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=20,  minDist=1, 
param1=30, param2=50, minRadius=10, maxRadius=50)
for circle in circles[0, :]:
     a, b = int(circle[0]), int(circle[1])
     radius = int(circle[2])
     cv2.circle(img=img, center=(a, b), radius=radius, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
cv2.imshow('Circle Segment', img), cv2.waitKey(0), cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem with the circle radius. Check the range.

Comment: specifically, param1 and param2... please do a little research on the API you use. opencv comes with documentation and tutorials.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I take the same radiuses in Matlab.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  I read the Documentation in Opencv they say that para1 and param2 get the hysteresis threshold of canny edge I performed this but still get a bad result.

Comment: I Change the parameters : circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image=edges, method=cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=20,  minDist=0.5, param1=200, param2=0.9, minRadius=10, maxRadius=56) and get better result but still the centers of the circles not correct like Matlab

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that you're applying canny and then opencv's houghcircles **also** applies canny (it's a dumb API, not orthogonal at all). keep your canny __only__ to watch what `houghcircles` will have to work with, but give houghcircles the gray image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I give the houghcircles gray image but I get a worse result: 'circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image=gray, method=cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=20,  minDist=1, param1=200, param2=0.9, minRadius=13, maxRadius=50)'

Comment: Where is your input image of coins without any graphics on them.?

Comment: @fmw42 The variable img contain  the coin image without any graphics you can plot this image: cv2.imshow('Orignal Image', img)

Comment: Where does coins2.png come from?  Please post, if you want help.

Comment: @fmw42 Hi sorry at first did not understand what you want the Image was taken from the skimage example Attached is a link: [link](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.8.0/auto_examples/plot_circular_hough_transform.html) If this library is installed on your computer then the image inside 'coing.png'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for the answers it was very helpful.
Attached the code that brought me almost the same MATLAB performance.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('coins2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # Convert the image to gray scale
thres=230
edges = cv2.Canny(image=gray, threshold1=thres, threshold2=thres/2, 
                  apertureSize=3, L2gradient=True)
cv2.imshow('Orignal Image', img), cv2.imshow('Edge Image', edges)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image=gray, method=cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=0.06,  
                           minDist=14, param1=thres, param2=30, minRadius=10, 
                           maxRadius=40)
for circle in circles[0, :]:
    a, b = int(circle[0]), int(circle[1])
    radius = int(circle[2])
    cv2.circle(img=img, center=(a, b), radius=radius, color=(255, 0, 0), 
               thickness=2)
    cv2.imshow('Circle Segment', img), cv2.waitKey(0), cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```